# Export a document in a json file from mongodb using php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection "form_configuration" and it contains a document which has field_id as "done" and i want to export that particular document from the database in a json file.My database name is mydb.

Take a look on what i'm trying to do but haven't had success yet...

```
exec("mongoexport -h ds059917.mongolab.com:59917 -d mydb -c form_configuration -q '{"form_configurations.form_id":"done"}' -u My Username -p My Password -o /var/www/html/form_conf.json ");
```

Comment: Are you gettin an error? Can you edit the error into the question? Have you tried running the mongoexport command from the command line? What do your documents look like? Is the field path `field_id` or `form_configurations.field_id`?

Comment: The problem is solved, the problem was not of mongoexport the problem was of permission to that folder www, u have to run the following commands to give permission: sudo usermod -a -G www-data www-data after this www-data group 
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www and at last www-data group
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, the problem was not of mongoexport the problem was of permission to that folder www, u have to run the following commands to give permission: 
sudo usermod -a -G www-data www-data 
after this 
www-data group sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www 
and at last 
www-data group sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www
After this it'll work fine